# CodeIgniter controller to view to another controller url

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

Say for example, I loaded a view from controller1

The url should be `index.php/controller1/<function where view is ran>`

Then from that view I have a link.

```
<a href='controller2/view'>View</a>
```

After clicking that link, the url now looks like this.

```
index.php/controller1/controller2/view
```

Is there a way to clear previous url_segment, or is there a better way to link to another controller's function.

Comment: I use `<?=base_url();?>index.php/controller/view` (obviously using `url` helper in `autoload.php`).

Answer (score 1):

Do.

```
<?=base_url(); ?>/controller2/view
```

Inside your href.

Comment: Is there some config to the CI to enable <?=$value?>

Instead of <?php echo $value; ?>

when i pass my codes to my friends with those in my value they often get printed out as values.

Comment: that's php5 new feature.. look at the 5th bullet point @ http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: The pretty version (with no possible double `//`) is `base_url('controller2/view')`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the link as

```
<a href='<?=base_url(); ?>controller2/view'>View</a>
```

remember that you have set the `base_url` in your `config/config.php` file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourSite';
```